# communicate between nginx and php-fpm podman

Tags: docker, podman

I want to set-up an nginx with php-fpm for running a symfony.

To do that I create a `pod` call `webservice` : `podman pod create --name webservice -p 8080:80`

And I launch a php-fpm :

```
podman run -ti \
--name php7 \
--pod webservice \
--volume ~/samus/bare-data/php:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
--volume ~/samus/bare-data/www:/var/www/html:rw \
docker.io/library/php:7.4-fpm-alpine
```

And finally a nginx :

```
podman run -ti \
--name nginx \
--pod webservice \
--volume ~/samus/bare-data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro \
--volume ~/samus/bare-data/www:/var/www/html \
docker.io/library/nginx:alpine
```

When I do that, the php tells me :

```
[08-Sep-2021 18:05:46] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
[08-Sep-2021 18:05:46] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

and the nginx :

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2021/09/08 18:05:52 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2021/09/08 18:05:52 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.21.1
2021/09/08 18:05:52 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 10.3.1 20210424 (Alpine 10.3.1_git20210424) 
2021/09/08 18:05:52 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.13.13-200.fc34.x86_64
2021/09/08 18:05:52 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 524288:524288
2021/09/08 18:05:52 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2021/09/08 18:05:52 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 17
2021/09/08 18:05:52 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 18
2021/09/08 18:05:52 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 19
2021/09/08 18:05:52 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 20
2021/09/08 18:05:52 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 21
2021/09/08 18:05:52 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 22
2021/09/08 18:05:52 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 23
2021/09/08 18:05:52 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 24
```

Here if I do `podman ps -a` I have the following result :

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                                 COMMAND               CREATED         STATUS                        PORTS                 NAMES
e63300d78306  k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.5                                        23 minutes ago  Up 23 minutes ago             0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp  0bb2d4aa79a9-infra
aca134de2fb3  docker.io/library/php:7.4-fpm-alpine  php-fpm               23 minutes ago  Up 23 minutes ago             0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp  php7
f7b19cc296ee  docker.io/library/nginx:alpine        nginx -g daemon o...  23 minutes ago  Up 23 minutes ago             0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp  nginx
```

The `127.0.0.1:8080` give me `The connection was reset`

Here I assume this is not normal to not have the 9000 port shared for the php.

But I'm a little bit out of knowledge to know why.

I tried to add the port to my pod (`podman pod create --name webservice -p 8080:80 -p 9000:9000`) but nothing new except the `0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp` everywhere.

For information my nginx conf (stored in `~/samus/bare-data/nginx/podman-nginx-confs` :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
        index index.php index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass    localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: What was the _podman_ version? Did you find a solution? It looks like the network issues I am facing today when running rootless _podman_. I am myself struggling making my containers reachable from the host machine after starting my pod definition using `podman play kube`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify port 9000 for the pod. Try to change this line in your nginx.conf from:

```
fastcgi_pass    localhost:9000;
```

to

```
fastcgi_pass    php7:9000;
```

Anyway, the answer is late, but it might help users with the same problem.

Comment: Not works, because localhost must be the service name, not the container name.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an almost 2 year old issue, but I struggled with this for 2 days and I figured it out just recently.

If you check your nginx's configuration on the container (`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`) you will see that it only includes files from `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` if the file extension is `conf`.

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf
```

So rename `~/samus/bare-data/nginx/podman-nginx-confs` to `~/samus/bare-data/nginx/podman-nginx-confs.conf` an it should work.

Also, `fastcgi_pass` doesn't care if you use `localhost` or `php7`. Both resolve to `127.0.0.1`.